# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7, mysql-connect

i have this problem with laravel, this is my .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=
LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and this is my `config/database`

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

i alway get error message `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`, i was changed `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=localhost` but it's not working.
this is my issue, thanks for help

Comment: Try adding DB_PORT = 33060; in .env file also try DB_HOST="localhost"

Comment: Can you also please provide your OS details and apache details like Xampp or mamp or ngnix ?

Comment: i try DB_PORT = 33060 and DB_HOST="localhost" but it's not working, my OS is Ubuntu 16.04, i use Xampp

Comment: Can you reinstall the project ? and then try. Also check is port 3306 is used by any other process

Comment: nahh :v all project laravel error, i think reason is laravel connect mysql, so.... i reinstall ubuntu and .... yep, it run correctly, thanks about your help !

Comment: Did you tried removing temp files....in windows it's in %temp% folder...idk about ubuntu temp files but it would help

Comment: i resolved that problem, thanks ! but i dont know how :v

Answer (score 0):

Add APP_URL=http://localhost in .env file.
Hope it will work

Comment: .env file not is problem

Comment: yep, i have try

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the server ram and the problem will be solved :)